# Enter value into drop down form Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, firefox, mechanize, enter

Im trying to write a perl script which enters a value into a drop down box on a webpage using Perl and the **WWW::Mechanize::Firefox** package. Here is the portion of the webapge source that has what im trying to input.

```
<div class="exp-pdp-size-and-quantity-container">
        <div
            class="exp-pdp-size-container exp-pdp-dropdown-container nsg-form--drop-down">
          <a class="nsg-form--drop-down--label nsg-font-family--platform" >
            <span class="js-selectBox-label">SIZE </span>
            <span class="js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option"></span>
          </a>
          <select name="skuAndSize"
                  class="exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown"
                  data-tooltiptext="Select a Size" required="required"
                  data-error="Select a Size" >
            <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock" value=""></option>


            <option 
                  name="skuId"
                  value="3613869:5"
                  data-label="(5)">
                              5
            </option>
```

That '5' will continue with the rest of the shoe sizes.

Here is part of my code

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_number( 1 );
$mech->select( "skuAndSize", $shoesize );
$mech->click( "ADD TO CART" );
```

Its return is basically saying that the `skuAndSize` doesnt exsist.
Here is the url of the website http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/free-4-flyknit-running-shoe/pid-1064825/pgid-1481072

**Can some one help me input a value into what I think would be `skuAndSize`** Thanks to whom ever can figure this out or put me in the right direction. Brett

Comment: show your code?  at least the part that isn't working

Comment: I added my non-working code to the post

Comment: I think you will find the form number should be 6. Also, there is no button named "ADD TO CART" - that is just the text content.

Comment: Changed `$mech->form_number( 1 );` to `$mech->form_number( 6 );` kept, everything the same still didn't work should I change anything else?

Comment: Scrach what I said before, changed that it seems to work now, toyed with how I called `skuAndSize` for a little and it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Requesting help in breaking the TOS of an external website.  http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/help/terms-conditions